# Posting data using Django unit testing not saving to backend

Tags: django, django-testing

I am creating a django app which i which implement most of my logic before the design aspect of the application.
I created a testcase for user registration but anytime I post to the registration url, it received my posted data but never populates it to database.

```py
class AuthTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def test_reg_index(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse_lazy('register'))
        return self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_registration(self):
        data = {
            'last_name': 'test_user',
            'first_name': 'test_user',
            'email': 'fashtop3@gmail.com',
            'phone': '08035112897',
        }
        response = self.client.post(reverse_lazy('register'), data)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)

    def test_login(self):
        # self.client.login(username='foo', password='bar')  # request.user is now user foo
        data = {
            'email': 'test_user@example.com',
            'password': 'pass123',
        }
        response = self.client.post(reverse_lazy('login'), data)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

```py
class RegisterView(FormView):
    """
    this handles users registration
    """
    form_class = RegForm
    template_name = "club/register.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("register")

    # def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    #     return super(RegisterView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print(form.errors.as_data)
        return super().form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """
        Process valid registration form
        :param form:
        :return: redirects to success_url
        """
        random_password = ''.join(secrets.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(6))
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                """Allow database transactions"""
                data = form.cleaned_data
                user = User.objects.create_user(
                    email=data['email'],
                    password=random_password,
                    remember_token=hashlib.sha1(str(datetime.now()).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
                )
                user.profile.last_name = data['last_name']
                user.profile.first_name = data['first_name']
                user.profile.phone = data['phone']
                user.save()
                send_notification.delay(user.pk, random_password)
                print('Reg success')
                messages.success(self.request, "Regular successfully registered "
                                               "please check your mail for verification",
                                 extra_tags="alert-success")
        except IntegrityError as e:
            print(e)
            messages.error(self.request, "Registration Failed: Email address already exist", extra_tags="alert-danger")
            return super(RegisterView, self).form_invalid(form)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            messages.error(self.request, "Registration Error, contact site administrator: ", extra_tags="alert-danger")
            return super(RegisterView, self).form_invalid(form)

        return super(RegisterView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After like two days I got a solution to my Qts..
In order to retain your data after a success unit test you have to subclass a TestCase from unittest otherwise to perform auto rollback then import TestCase from django.test.

Answer (score 3):

The `TestCase` class wraps each test in a transaction, which is rolled back after the transaction (see the relevant [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#testcase)).

Even if `test_registration` successfully registers a user, it won't be available in `test_login`.

I would suggest creating a user for testing in a `setUpClass` method.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you need to use **import unittest** instead of **from django.test import TestCase**

And in your unit test class extends **TestCase** with **unittest.TestCase**

see the example below

```
import unittest 
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    .......
```